# Can run selenium scripts from IDE but not from cmd

Tags: python, selenium, command-line

I'm trying to make a script in python that takes input from cmd and uses selenium to access my email account, now I'm just testing the script to just print the inputs and I'm getting a from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'.

What I don't get is that when I'm running a different script that doesn't use cmd inputs it runs correctly.

Note that I've already installed selenium via pip and I use from selenium import webdriver.

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you need to do `pip install selenium` before you run the script.

If you are on Linux, do same, but probably need `sudo pip install selenium`.

Comment: I've already installed selenium, I can run a different script just from running it from Atom but the one that takes inputs from cmd says module not found even when I import it the same way I did to the other script

Comment: This is not my issue I have already installed the selenium as I stated earlier